# Move image based on window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am having a heck of a time getting this to work.

I have an absolutely positioned image, right:0, top:0 to it pins to the right side of the window.

What I need, is if the window is resized (or is currently at) a certain width to start moving the image further to the right based on a couple of numbers...

Here is my current attempts:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var $ww = $(window).width();
    moveImage($ww);
});
    
$(window).smartresize(function(){
    var $ww = $(window).width();
    moveImage($ww);
});
    
function moveImage($w){
    if($w <= 1863){
        var $p1img = $('.panel-1-image');   
        $pos = 1410 - $w;
        $p1img.css('right', '-' + $pos + 'px');
    }
}
```

`.panel-1-image` is the image in question.

So, both the image, and the content to the left of it have a combined total width of 1410 pixels.  which on a screen size larger than 1863 pixels looks fine.

I want to move the image further to the right, if the screen size is smaller, or gets resized smaller than this, so the image does not over/under lap the content next to it.

I'm using jQuery 1.7, and the jQuery smartresize plugin here: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

What am I doing wrong?

## Screenshots

## Full

[image]

## Smaller

[image]

## Smaller Still

[image]

The edge of the magnifying glass should never overlap the content

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/o7thwd/YmQpt/

Comment: This question is terribly unclear. What snaplemouton said is likely true, you can probably use pure CSS for this. We can't test that theory though because we don't have enough of your code, a jsFiddle would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the math you've provided in your function.

```
function moveImage($w){
  if($w <= 1863){
    var $p1img = $('.panel-1-image');   
    $pos = 1410 - $w;
    $p1img.css('right', '-' + $pos + 'px');
  }
}
```

You're looking at the difference the content size including the image, and your browser.
What you need to be detecting is at what width the image looks good, and the browser size.
This way, for every pixel that the browser has, less than what normally looks good, it will move the image over that many pixels.

This function here would work:

```
function moveImage($w){
  if($w <= 1863){
    var $p1img = $('.panel-1-image');   
    $pos = 1864 - $w;
    $p1img.css('right', '-' + $pos + 'px');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, and for reading the requirements in the question.

Comment: Absolutely, glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1410px){
    //Add CSS here
}
```

Just put in new CSS to either resize your image, move it, display:none or anything kind of CSS you need to apply on it to fit your needs.

You shouldn't need javascript unless you want to do something that CSS cannot do.

Edit: After posting your fiddle, I believe this is what you were looking for: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YmQpt/2/)

Basically, you just need to put the image inside the content and set the style to right:-360px;

No need of Jscript in the end. Hope this is what you needed.

Edit #2: Scratch that, it's overlapping the rest of the content, let me see if I can fix that.

Edit #3: This should do the trick now... Since I don't have the CSS in the fiddle, here's a screenshot of what I did.

I removed the z-index from the panel content

[image]

Comment: please re-read my question.  I specifically state that I am resizing the window... and need the image to move further right on the resize event... on top of... the requirement is for less than 1863, not 1410  -1

Comment: Then you can write max-width: 1863px instead. It was a little confusing with the 1410px size on the content. If you could provide a preview or a jsFiddle of your code it would help better understand. Usually, those kind of problem can be fixed through CSS and rarely require Jscript. Are you trying to keep an image to the right of some content? Are you trying to move it away from the content? Is the rest of the content shrinking?

Comment: Rest of the content is not shrinking.  I am trying to keep the image pinned to the right side of the window... on resizing (albeit this does not simply mean it will be sized once, then resized once), the image pulls in to meet the right side of the content... but then starts to overlap it...  yes, even using a media query does this.  Hence, the -1, and now I have to flag because no-body reads the question...

Comment: You should post an example of JsFiddle of your page. There is no way to help you if we can't see what you are trying to achieve. Even images of what it looks like or what it should looks like will help your question get answered. Don't go saying people don't read the question if you didn't give us enough informations to help you in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use a width set to a certain percentage?

Otherwise just check de browser width and change accordingly.
Do you have a screenshot or jsfiddle to further clearify what your intention is?

And why not use jquery's resize()? (http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: I don't need to change the image dimensions

Comment: You could use a background-image.
set the background of the body as 
url("IMG-LINK") no-repeat fixed right center / contain #FFFFFF

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to your approach, the problem is syntax in function moveImage. You are missing curly brackets and using coma instead of semicolon.

Change line:

```
$p1img.css('right', '-' + $pos + 'px');
```

to this:

```
$p1img.css({'right':'-' + $pos + 'px'});
```

and it should work.

Comment: This sort of does it.  I definately moves now, but I think the math is off.   is it ok if I shoot a link to show?

Comment: The question is kind of unclear as mentioned by others before. Could you provide [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code and explanation to help us understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds from your question and comments that your image is inside an element in your html that is positioned relatively. In this case, your image will be absolutely positioned to its parent (the relative object). [This](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) post on CSS Tricks explains it well. All you need to do is to move the image outside its container and it should work.

(I would post this as a comment to @snaplemouton's answer, but I don't have the rep yet.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @snaplemouton is the best solution possible.

Using the Javascript you are can cause issues, your browser and it's content will blink on resize from time to time, etc.  And you're using too many processes that aren't necessary.

It's not semantic nor fully responsive, as different browsers detect pixels differently.
Hence why on some browsers your image may not overlap the text, and others it will.

Please take a look at this article: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Media Queries allow you to easily change the css of your content based on the size of the browser, and even media type, such as mobile, etc.

So as snaplemouton mentioned above:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1410px){
    .panel-image-1{
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}
```

Basically says, that if the screen is smaller than 1410px, change my 'detective image' to be 50% width and 50% height.

Also, your image should not be an image tag. 
If you're using an image strictly for design, that adds no value to the content, you should include it via css, not html.

Comment: It's a good explanation on why using javascript when it's doable by CSS is bad. Only thing I might add is the @media screen in this case should be used for mobile support or if the image is too big at a certain size to fit what is needed. Don't know why someone would downvote you so I fixed that wrong.

Comment: Thanks snaple.
The reason I suggested Media Queries was because the page is actually rather responsive.  His Fiddle shows this.  Plus, I personally have had a lot of issues when it comes to browser-resizing based functions.

Answer (score -1):

Option one:

```
body{
position:relative;
}
img{position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:0px;}
```

Now just control the window (body) as you want and the image will follow

Option two:

```
body{background-image:[your image]; background-position:90% 90%; background-size:10% 10%;}
```

You will need to again control the window/body positioning as you want. And change the percentages based on the size you want the image to be.